# Google Places API Request denied from Amzon EC2

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to get restaurant details by using 'google place api', but it always returns "Request_denied" , here are the details:

I have created Key for Server APPS ( with IP Locking) and added my amazon EC2 server DNS ip address in the Allowed IPS (54.235.221.241)

Key for server apps (with IP locking)
API key:AIzaSyAnyPjWi6sEqeCa8jr2CDc45J43kdTyjjg
IPs: 54.235.221.241
Activated on:   Apr 17, 2013 11:15 PM

I am getting request denied when i am trying to execute ( Programatically by using JAVA) below URL from Amazon EC2 server
 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.4464863,-122.1612654&radius=5000&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAnyPjWi6sEqeCa8jr2CDc45J43kdTyjjg
Any advice would be much appreciated.